# Understanding specific python dictionary creation using for i loop

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I just started reading through Dave Peticolas tutorial on Twisted (http://krondo.com/blog/?p=1247), and quickly going through his early examples using Python sockets, I came across a line of code that I can't wrap my head around. The code is on his github, specifically https://github.com/jdavisp3/twisted-intro/blob/master/async-client/get-poetry.py, but the context doesn't really matter.

Here is the line:

```
sock2task = dict([(s, i + 1) for i, s in enumerate(sockets)])
```

Where sockets is a list of sockets.

This line will create a dictionary in the form of

```
{<sock3 object>: 3, <sock3 object>: 2, <sock3 object>: 1}
```

however, I just don't understand how.

Trying to get an equivalent statement, I came up with

```
sock2task = dict(enumerate(sockets, start=1))
```

however this results in

```
{1: <sock3 object>, 2: <sock3 object>, 3: <sock3 object>}
```

which has the keys and values swapped, and is in reverse.

So how does it work? In the full code, neither s or i are defined..

Thanks, Matt

Comment: Did you notice that it is *you* who implemented the so called "swap ? `(s, i + 1) for i, s` :) Further, dictionary (map) is not an ordered datastructure.

Comment: Equivalently: `dict(zip(sockets, itertools.count(1)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line in question is the initialization of a dictionary using list comprehension. To break it down:

A dict can be initialized like this

```
dict = dict([(key0, value0), ...)])  # make a dictionary out of a list of tuples
```

The list comprehension in the book is made up of following components:

1.

```
# "for every index i and corresponding entry s in sockets"
for i, s in enumerate(sockets)
```

2.

```
# a tuple of the socket s and its index + 1: `i + 1`
(s, i + 1)
```

3.

```
# "Make a list in which for every index i 
# and corresponding entry s in sockets there is a tuple (s, i + 1)"
[(s, i + 1) for i, s in enumerate(sockets)]
```

And so:

```
# "Convert this whole thing into a dictionary!" 
dict([(s, i + 1) for i, s in enumerate(sockets)])
```

An equivalent code would be:

```
sock2task = {}
for index, socket in enumerate(sockets):
    sock2task[socket] = index + 1
```

The outputted dictionary starts at 3 by coincidence, because dictionaries are not ordered.

I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: So, if I understand your explanation correctly, the left side of the comma iterates through the sockets list, using s (s = index of socket), assigns it to i and adds 1, for the index. Then on the right side of the comma, it's just a normal enumeration? I still don't get why it starts at 3 though..

Comment: Oh, no there is no assignment to i. I try to explain it like this:
1.: `for i, s in enumerate(sockets)` = "for every index i and corresponding entry s in sockets".

2.: `(s, i + 1)` is a tuple of the socket s and its index + 1: i + 1.

3.: So `[(s, i + 1) for i, s in enumerate(sockets)]` = "Make a list in which for every index i and corresponding entry s in sockets there is a tuple (s, i + 1)".

4.: And so `dict([(s, i + 1) for i, s in enumerate(sockets)])` = "Convert this whole thing into a dictionary!"

It starts at 3 by coincidence, because dictionaries are not ordered.

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you for explaining it in such detail.

Answer (score 1):

You have to dive into [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get some necessary background.

Despite that, you can create a dictionary from a list of pairs, where the first value will be assigned as key and the second as value. The following code has the same idea but it will help you to understand how it works.

```
result = {}
for index, s in enumerate(sockets):
    result[s] = index + 1
```

Your code is getting the inverse result because you **did not** inverted the values returned by `enumerate` (as you can see in my example and at the original code).

Answer (score 0):

```
sock2task = dict([(s, i + 1) for i, s in enumerate(sockets)])
                                  ^
```

This is a list comprehension + tuple unpacking, cast to a dict.

A list comprehension takes the form of `[f(i) for i in iterable]`. In this case, `iterable` is `enumerate(sockets)`, which creates a tuple of two elements.

Tuples can be unpacked. ie `i,j = (0,1)` would assign `0` to `i` and `1` to `j`.

So, basically, `i` and `s` are created where I have the caret sign pointing.

(Incidentally, in python 2.7+ you can also use the dictionary comprehension. `sock2task = { s: i + 1 for i,s in enumerate(sockets)}`